# What Does Automated Process User Not Have Access To?

Tags: apex, automation, sandboxpostcopy, automated-process

While working on a SandboxPostCopy script, I came across the following warning on a Salesforce article:

[image]

So it sounds like there are certain things that cannot be done with the script, but I haven't seen a list of the things that are not possible.

Is there a comprehensive list of things that cannot be done by the Automated Process user or does it need to be trial and error to figure it out?